# Prevent user from editing own custom profile

Tags: apex, trigger, permissions, before-trigger, custom-profile

We have a custom profile where we enabled `Manage Profiles and Permission Sets` permissions but we do not want the user to be able to edit the custom profile assigned to them.

E.g. I am assigned ABC custom profile so I should be able to edit and save custom profile XYZ and all other profiles but not ABC.

I can't seem to get this to work with a `User` trigger.
Any ideas?

***note**: The user should be able to update their own `Personal Information, change password, etc.`*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly - because Profile is not available for triggers or Validation rules.

One approach would be a daily schedule-triggered Flow that looked at the `SetupAuditLog` object for Profile edits and compared those edits against the editing user's profile.  If said user edited their own Profile, you could publish something to the security team, via an email, chatter post, or slack integration

Comment: Thank you for your answer.